# COVID-19 impact on university tuition fee

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, tuition, covid-19

If US universities switch to online education during the Coronavirus crisis, what will the impact it will have on tuition fees?

Comment: Ask your university, won’t be the same for all.

Comment: There will probably (just a guess) be no impact unless it goes on long enough that there is a general permanent restructuring of education nationwide. That seems unlikely.